# java.lang.InstantiationException: org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModelWrapper with PF 5.2 and partial state saving enabled

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable, filtering

I have a JSF page with 2 data tables in two different tab in tabview.
The first data table is lazy the second is no-lazy and its value is an attribute of value of first data table. When I try to filter with global filter in the second data table after the first character I get this exception.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModelWrapper
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:153)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.restoreState(ComponentStateHelper.java:306)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1628)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.restoreState(UIData.java:1750)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.restoreState(UIData.java:1305)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:380)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.FullVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(FullVisitContext.java:151)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:821)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UINamingContainer.visitTree(UINamingContainer.java:174)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UITabPanel.visitTree(UITabPanel.java:920)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.restoreView(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:367)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.restoreView(StateManagerImpl.java:138)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(ViewHandlingStrategy.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.restoreView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:585)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.restoreView(MultiViewHandler.java:150)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.restoreView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:353)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:197)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at it.ingeniaonline.platform.ws.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:20)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:512)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:854)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:926)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: org.primefaces.model.SelectableDataModelWrapper
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:364)
    at javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver.restore(StateHolderSaver.java:150)
    ... 60 more
```

I am using JBoss EAP 6.4 with Mojara 2.2.8 and PrimeFaces 5.2 and in `web.xml` I have `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING = true`.

If I set `javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING = false`, then I have no problem.  Also with PrimeFaces 5.0.4 I have no error.

Comment: I tried mojarra 2.2.11 and i have the same problem, i haven't primefaces 5.3-snapshot the last version of primefaces is 5.2.8

Comment: 5.2.8 comes close, but 5.3-SNAPSHOT can be easily build from source

Comment: I found the problem, the problem is that the use of c:forEach to create dynamic tabs within TabView and have an index that used to generate the specific ID that will be updated later by other parts of the page.

How do I get an index (like rowIndex in datatable) without using c:foreach in a tabview component?